# MinGW File and folder listing problems

Tags: c, directory, mingw32, file-search

Here's part of code for my application I'm porting to windowsXp initially written on Ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int list_files(char *parentdir)
{
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *de = NULL;
  char subdirs[1000][1000];
  int isubdirs = 0;

  char rootdir[1000];
  strcpy(rootdir, parentdir);

  FILE *fp = fopen("list.txt", "w");

seek:
  dir = opendir(rootdir);
  if (!dir) {
    printf("ERROR: [ %s ]", rootdir);
    perror("Couldn't opendir: ");
  }
  else {
    de = readdir(dir);
    if (!de) {
      printf("ERROR:[ %s ]", rootdir);
      perror("Couldn't readdir ");
      goto out;
    }
    if (strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0) {
      fprintf(fp, "%s\\%s\n", rootdir, de->d_name);
      printf("ADDED: %s\\%s\n", rootdir, de->d_name);
    }
    while ((de = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
      if (!strcmp(de->d_name, "..") || !strcmp(de->d_name, "."))
        continue;
      fprintf(fp, "%s\\%s\n", rootdir, de->d_name);
      printf("ADDED: %s\\%s\n", rootdir, de->d_name);
      struct stat s;
      stat(de->d_name, &s);
      if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
      {
        strcpy(subdirs[isubdirs], rootdir);
        strcat(subdirs[isubdirs], "\\");
        strcat(subdirs[isubdirs], de->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", subdirs[isubdirs]);
        isubdirs++;
      }
      /* Not working in WinXP
      if (de->d_type == 4) {
        strcpy(subdirs[isubdirs], rootdir);
        strcat(subdirs[isubdirs], "/");
        strcat(subdirs[isubdirs], de->d_name);
        isubdirs++;
      }
      */
    }
    if (isubdirs > 0) {
      strcpy(rootdir, subdirs[--isubdirs]);
      goto seek;
    }
  }
out:

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Now problem is in output file i get:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\New Folder\00.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\New Folder\1
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\New Folder\2
```

Only files in parentdir listed, but not in subdirs (1 and 2 both not empty "folders")
I'm testing in Virtualbox.

Comment: Well it was obvious after checking stat's status, it was given a wrong path ... (embarrassed)
Cheers!